# Add Chart to our LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, css, html, charts

i want to get something just like this , is it possible with LWC , with the possibility that the arrow change the position in depend of the condition that i will make in my JS ,
should i just use the Charts ?

```
import Chart from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Chart';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is generally possible but not easily out of the box.

It involves using a charting library and implementing it in LWC.

There are ready to use examples by Salesforce Apps on the AppExchange: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000MBarPEAT

There is also a recipe in https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsChartjs

Comment: thank you for your help